Derivation of the solar resource at Earth's surface
I am reading Jenny Nelson's The Physics of Solar Cells and am a bit confused with the derivation of the solar irradiance at the Earth's atmosphere she supplies. I'll outline it here, and I provide also pictures in case that's not clear.
She begins with the statement of the spectral photon flux $\beta(E, s, \theta, \phi)$; no problems here, I've seen this derivation in Reif's statistical mechanics text. Importantly, we emphasize that this is the flux (per unit energy and per unit solid angle of photon direction) of photons per unit area of the blackbody's surface area. I'll come back to this point later as it's the source of my confusion.
As regards the solar resource at the Earth, Nelson then goes on to integrate this flux over the angles $\theta < \theta_{sun}$ in order to obtain the photon flux, $b$, at the Earth. Now the trouble for me is that this sort of geometric argument seems to have two troubling premises:

That we are considering some surface element (I'll call it $dS'$ to make it special) of the blackbody (our Sun here) which is directly "in line" with the Earth, so that the only photons being captured by the Earth are those photons which were emitted from this $dS'$, and nothing else, i.e. all the photons from any other $dS \neq dS'$ (please forgive the abuse of notation in treating the $dS$ as actual pieces of surface).

Throughout the derivation, we never integrate over the surface area element $dS$. It seems that, by the end, we are treating the flux $b$ (and irradiance $L$) on a per unit of Earth's surface area basis, even though $dS$ was defined on the surface of the blackbody.


Am I mistaken in having the two concerns above and, if not, can someone explain how these concerns are waved away/justified?
Derivation page 1
Derivation page 2

Is the first question the same as asking whether photons travel in straight lines from the sun to the earth? And the second question asking why we can treat [the cross sectional flux that the earth "carves out" from the sphere of radiation radiating from the sun] as a flux at each point on the surface area of the earth? (The latter only works if you adjust for factors of $4\pi$ and average over the surface of the earth)

I don't think so, @QuantumMechanic , but I could well be wrong. My objections: 1) My concern here was that Nelson is only counting photons which emerge from the little piece $dS'$ which "directly faces" the Earth, and which exit within the cone defined by $\theta_{sun}$. But shouldn't we also count photons from other (probably nearby to $dS'$) pieces where the photon exits said $dS$ with some large angle $\theta$ and the right $\phi$, so that it also hits Earth? Photons are assumed (I think they just do?) to travel in a straight line (once emerging from the blackbody modelling our Sun).


This is not quite the question, though I think it would be a subsequent consideration. My second question precedes the one you're describing here. I am here concerned with how Nelson goes from a flux emanating from some element of the blackbody's surface area ($dS$) to flux on an element of Earth surface area without apparent justification. I think this dovetails with my first question and perhaps some of it would have to do with what you describe, but I think there is more going on.


Oh I see what you're saying for #1. It's as if, not only are all of the photons emitted from the surface of the sun, but it is also assumed that they are all emitted radially. Right? The point is probably that such effects average out: the total energy radiated to a sphere of radius 1000 is the same as the total energy from a sphere of radius 100, or 10, or 1, just spread out differently. Go all the way to tiny radii and it's like everything was emitted radially. Or, if some light sneaks in from "the side" then it means some light sneaks out from the party directly facing us, averaging out

#2 if the earth was a giant solar panel instead of a sphere, would you be happy saying it had the same flux as that on the sun? You will need a conversion factor in terms of the radius of the sun vs the radius of how far this solar panel is from the sun (but we typically measure solar flux near the earth anyway so we actually get the flux at the earth more readily than the flux at the radius of the sun)

@QuantumMechanic Re: #1, yes, exactly this. The concern still remains for me insofar as we have not integrated over $S$ at any point in the derivation. It's left there as a "free variable", as it were. On your explanation, we would expect to have integrated over $S$ somehow, right? Re: #2, yes, I can imagine some correspondence rule between some surface area of the Sun and the amount of light captured by the Earth (again, using some averaging out of the obtuse angle photons you mention above). But Nelson doesn't seem to be doing this?

#1 okay great, then you can integrate over everything and divide by the whole surface area again, then you'll be happy to see that the dS is the same as if all the light is emitted radially. Haven't read the textbook for #2, but that's the standard derivation that I recall

Here, spectral photon flux $\beta$ refers to the number of photons that leave a unit area of a black body (the Sun) $dS'$ and reach a unit area of a target (the Earth) $dS$ with a certain frequency $\omega$. So to get the total number of photons that arrive to the Earth you must sum over all $dS'$, $dS$ and $\omega$. Sum in this case is integrating because we are in the continuum. So to the total number of photons $N_s$ are:
\begin{equation}
N_s = \int_0^\infty\int_{S_{Earth}}\int_{S_{sun}} \beta() dS' dS d\omega
\end{equation}
But as you can follow in the derivation you mention, from equation 2.1 to equation 2.2 he is only integrating over $dS'$, so they are calculating the numbre of photons that reach a part of the Earth $dS$ (maybe here is your problem, $dS$ is on the Earth) coming from any part of the Sun. To integrate over all the Sun surface you can perform a coordinates change and integrate over solid angle $d\Omega$.

So about your questions:

Yes, only parts of the black body that are in-line with the surface of Earth contribute to the radiation, but if you think on that, you can make a straight line between any part part of the Earth and the half of the Sun. Hope that the image helps you with that.

As I said above, dS is defined on the Earth surface, $d\Omega$ is what represent the Sun surface, in the notes you facilitate $dS$ is not defined, so take into account that all the problem is reversible, you can consider $dS$ over the Sun, but then $d\Omega$ represents the Earth surface.


